# T-SQL - How to search for nth character in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where the 6th and 7th character in a string need to equal '73'. I tried using `LIKE '%73%'` but the problem is sometimes SQL Server will hit on other 73s that could be in the string. Is there a way to search only the 6th and 7th characters in the string?

Thank you all so much for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )

```
SELECT mycolumn 
FROM mytable
WHERE SUBSTRING ( mycolumn ,6 , 2 ) = '73'
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `like`, you can do:

```
where col like '_____73%'
```

Of course, the other solutions suggesting `substring()` are also very sensible.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YourColumn,6,2) Result
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Which you can use as a filter:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE SUBSTRING(YourColumn,6,2) = '73';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for SQL Server

```
select *
from MyTable
where CHARINDEX('73', MyString) = 6
```

This finds where string '73' starts at position 6

Comment: You will likely pay performance penalty for using this. As it has to scan the MyString for occurence of `73` to get its index. You will be better off with SUBSTRING. And it will sometimes miss records where another 73 is before position 6.

Comment: @MarekVitek:The performance penalty is same as substring solution

Comment: @TheGameiswar for short strings the difference will be really small. But consider some longer string, then you will have to iterate through it until you find what you are looking for or until you hit the end. It is expensive. While substring will just look at those two chars. BTW: solution that Gordon Linoff provided might be faster that use of substring. SQL Server engine is tuned up to be more performing in some cases.

Comment: Here are the numbers for the query like `select last_name from contact where SUBSTRING(last_name, 4,5) = 'ek'`: SUBSTRING `CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 15 ms` CHARINDEX `CPU time = 109 ms,  elapsed time = 106 ms`

Comment: The version with LIKE is little bit slower `CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 21 ms` sometimes even CPU time is longer compared to SUBSTRING.